# dropify data-allowed-file-extensions not working

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, dropify

I am using [dropify](https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify) for styling the file upload elements in my form. but I noticed that `data-allowed-file-extensions` parameter is not working, validation of input file extensions is not happening. Anyone worked with dropify and faced similar issue before?

My input field code - this field is accepting any file extension.

```
 <input type="file" name="thumbnail_2"  class="dropify" id="thumbnail_2" data-allowed-file-extensions="png jpg jpeg" data-max-file-size="1M" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your *dropify.min.js* or *dropify.js* to the latest version from https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify

Most probably you are using old one without file-extensions feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo#basic-example-7

```
<div class="file-loading">
    <input id="input-b7" name="input-b7[]" multiple type="file" class="file" data-allowed-file-extensions='["csv", "txt"]'>
</div>
```